# How to specify different sequence frame images for multiple planes

Tags: python

[image]

If there are hundreds of planes in the scene and hundreds of sequence images in the folder, how can they be mapped at one time？
How to write such a script？

Comment: I thought I should mention that there is a Blender add-on "Import-Export: Import Images as Planes" that can be enabled under  Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons. I tried it out and it can import multiple images as planes by going to File -> Import -> Images as Planes and selected the image sequence in the file explorer and then importing. You can even offset the images in the z-axis and control the spacing. Do you still need a script knowing the existence of this add-on?

Comment: Thank you, but I seem to have forgotten to say that I have made animation for the plane. This must be done by adding the plane first, and then adding the image